# Any ideas for this cyclic inequality?

Tags: inequality, fractions, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, holder-inequality

> If $a,b,c,d>0$ and $a+b+c+d=8$, prove that $$\frac{a}{b^2+2b}+ \frac{b}{c^2+2c}+\frac{c}{d^2+2d}+\frac{d}{a^2+2a}\geqslant\frac{16}{(a+c)(b+d)}.$$

I tried to use Titu Andreescu's inequality, but i didn't got anywhere. Can anyone give me another idea?

[image]

Comment: Please post your efforts (workings) when using Titu Andreescu's inequality, whether it lead anywhere or not. After all, it's possible that your path was in the right direction, though you may have missed or felt stuck and concluded it was a failed attempt.  It's always good to have extra eyes.  Again, please edit your post to include your work in using the inequality.

Comment: @amWhy I have edited, i hope now it’s ok.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Radu!

Comment: @Radu Andrei Your last inequality is wrong, which says that we need to find another way.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg  In all fairness, the asker did say in the post that their attempt did not get anywhere.  I thought it would be useful for us all to know what was tried, and the computations, to discern if the asker was on the right track, but took a mis-step, or needs to find another way.  I appreciate any further suggestions or help you'd like to give to the asker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Holder and AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b^2+2b}=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}ab\sum\limits_{cyc}a(b+2)\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{b(b+2)}}{\sum\limits_{cyc}ab\sum\limits_{cyc}a(b+2)}\geq\frac{(a+b+c+d)^3}{(a+c)(b+d)\sum\limits_{cyc}(ab+2a)}=$$
$$=\frac{512}{(a+c)(b+d)((a+c)(b+d)+16)}\geq\frac{512}{(a+c)(b+d)\left(\left(\frac{a+c+b+d}{2}\right)^2+16\right)}=$$
$$=\frac{16}{(a+c)(b+d)}.$$
I used the following Holder for three sequences.

> Let $a_1$, $a_2$,..., $a_n$, $b_1$, $b_2$,..., $b_n$, $c_1,$ $c_2,$... $c_n$, $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ be positive numbers. Prove that:
>   $$(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^{\alpha}(b_1+b_2+...+b_n)^{\beta}(c_1+c_2+,,,+c_n)^{\gamma}\geq$$$$\geq\left(\left(a_1^{\alpha}b_1^{\beta}c_1^{\gamma}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}}+\left(a_2^{\alpha}b_2^{\beta}c_2^{\gamma}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}}+...+\left(a_n^{\alpha}b_n^{\beta}c_n^{\gamma}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}}\right)^{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}$$

Comment: Sir, can you tell me why $${\sum\limits_{cyc}ab\sum\limits_{cyc}a(b+2)\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{b(b+2)}}\geq{(a+b+c+d)^3}$$ .Thank you